# Haskell: function folde: Couldn't match expected type `a' with actual type `Expr'

Tags: haskell

I have a data type
`data Expr = Val Int | Add Expr Expr`

and I have to define a function "folde" of type
`folde :: (Int -> a) -> (a -> a -> a) -> Expr -> a`
such that folde f g replaces each Val constructor in an expression by the function f, and each Add constructor by the function g

I've written such code:

```
data Expr = Val Int | Add Expr Expr

folde :: (Int -> a) -> (a -> a -> a) -> Expr -> a
folde f g (Val n) = f n
folde f g (Add z x) = g z x
```

but I've received the error

```
 Couldn't match expected type `a' with actual type `Expr'
      `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          folde :: forall a. (Int -> a) -> (a -> a -> a) -> Expr -> a
        at C:\code\haskell\types.hs:51:1-49
    * In the first argument of `g', namely `z'
      In the expression: g z x
      In an equation for `folde': folde f g (Add z x) = g z x
    * Relevant bindings include
        g :: a -> a -> a (bound at C:\code\haskell\types.hs:53:9)
        f :: Int -> a (bound at C:\code\haskell\types.hs:53:7)
        folde :: (Int -> a) -> (a -> a -> a) -> Expr -> a
```

Could you clarify where is the error. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Shouldn't this be `g (folde f g z) (folde f g x)`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You here have as second clause:

```
folde :: (Int -> a) -> (a -> a -> a) -> Expr -> a
folde f g (Val n) = f n
folde f g (Add z x) = g z x
```

Based on the data constructor, `Add` has two `Expr`s. So that means that both `z` and `x` have as type `x, z :: Expr`. You thus can not call `g z x`, since `g` has type `g :: a -> a -> a`.

What you need to do is perform *recursion* on the two items, like:

```
folde :: (Int -> a) -> (a -> a -> a) -> Expr -> a
folde f g (Val n) = f n
folde f g (Add z x) = g (folde f g z) (folde f g x)
```

or with a helper function:

```
folde :: (Int -> a) -> (a -> a -> a) -> Expr -> a
folde f g = go
    where go (Val n) = f n
          go (Add z x) = g (go z) (go x)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to define Expr, folde and eval like this:

```hs
data Expr a = Val a | Add (Expr a) (Expr a) | Mul (Expr a) (Expr a)

folde :: (a -> a) -> (a -> a -> a) -> (a -> a -> a) -> Expr a -> a
folde f g h (Val n) = f n
folde f g h (Add m n) = g (folde f g h m) (folde f g h n)
folde f g h (Mul m n) = h (folde f g h m) (folde f g h n)

eval :: Num a => Expr a -> a
eval = folde id (+) (*)
```